# Solving an optimization problem bounded by conditional constrains

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

Basically, I have a dataset that contains 'weights' for some (207) variables, some are more important than the others for determining the class variable (binary) and therefore they are bigger etc. at the end all weigths are summed up across all columns so that the resulting cumulative weight is obtained for each observation.
If this weight is higher then some number  then class variable is 1 otherwise is 0. I do have true labels for a class variable so the problem is to minimize false positives.

The thing is, for me it looks like a OR problem as it's about finding optimal weights. However, I am not sure if there is an OR method for such problem, at least I have not heard about one. Question is: does anyone recognize this type of problems and can send some keywords for me to research?

Another thing of course is to predict that with machine learning rather then deterministic methods but I need to do it this way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are the variables discrete (integer numbers etc) or continuous (floating point numbers)?

If they are discrete, it sounds like the knapsack problem, which constraint solvers like [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) ([see this training that builds a knapsack solver](https://learn.openshift.com/middleware/courses/middleware-kogito/optaplanner-knapsack)) excel at.

If they are continuous, look for an LP solver, like CPLEX.

Either way, you'll get much better results than machine learning approaches, because neural nets et al are great at pattern recognition use cases (image/voice recognition, prediction, catagorization, ...), but consistently inferior for constraint optimization problems (like this, I presume).